# Updated to Canary 3.0 and Gradle Failed Execution on run

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have updated Canary to 3.0, and now when i try to launch an app have this message:

```
Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.

Cause: org.gradle.tooling.BuildActionExecuter.forTasks([Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/gradle/tooling/BuildActionExecuter;
```

I have this problem in all my projects.
Have tried to clean and rebuild project but nothing. What could it be?

**SOLVED**

Uninstall and reinstall Canary solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Change the gradle in `dependencies { }` version to:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1'
```

For me thats works.